# How to write query in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

Code:

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT
        message,to_id,from_id,MAX(created) AS created
    FROM
        ".MEMBER_MSG."
    WHERE
            (to_id='".$uid."' OR from_id='".$uid."')
        AND
            from_id != '".$uid."'
        AND
            (to_delete='1' OR from_delete='1')
        AND
            is_chat='1'
    GROUP BY
        from_id,to_id
    ORDER by
        created DESC
");
```

I want to write above query in CakePHP. How to write in CakePHP?

**Edit:**

My CakePHP code:

```
$condition = array(
    'OR' => array(
        'AND' => array(
            'Message.from_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'),
            'Message.to_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
        ),
        array(
            'AND' => array(
                'Message.from_id' => $userid['User']['id'],
                'Message.to_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
            )
        )
    ),
    'is_chat' => '1',
    array(
        'OR' => array(
            'AND' => array(
                'Message.from_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'),
                'Message.from_delete' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'Message.to_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'),
                    'Message.to_delete' => '1'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This code is working but not getting the accurate result

**MySQL Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `is_view` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0-Not Viewed, 1-Viewed',
  `is_flag` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=No, 1=Yes',
  `is_chat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '0=No, 1=Yes',
  `from_delete` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0-Deleted by From, 1-Not',
  `to_delete` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0-Deleted by To, 1-Not',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `reply_count` smallint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from_id` (`from_id`),
  KEY `to_id` (`to_id`),
  KEY `from_delete` (`from_delete`),
  KEY `to_delete` (`to_delete`),
  KEY `is_view` (`is_view`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: I gave lot of effort but not getting my result. can you please check my question again. I have updated my CakePHP code

Comment: The sql query you're executing (from the sql log) would highlight just how far from the desired result that find call is. As Eagle points out - there's a logic bug with the query preventing from_id matches. However: clear question +1.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is that inside your `or` statements you have some values without keys, giving you unproper answer.

Maybe this conditions will help. Note that I did it based on your mysql query rather than your cake `$conditions` variable:

```
$conditions = array(
    'OR' => array(
        'to_id' => $uid,
        'from_id' => $uid
    ),
    'from_id !=' => $uid,
    'OR' => array(
        'to_delete' => 1,
        'from_delete' => 1
    ),
    'is_chat' => 1
);
```

Still, it's contradictory that you have conditions `from_id = 1` and `from_id != 1`

Answer (score -1):

If you want make it easy:

[CakeBook: raw query](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query)

```
$this->Message->query("SELECT message,to_id,from_id,MAX(created) AS created FROM ".MEMBER_MSG." WHERE (to_id='".$uid."' OR from_id='".$uid."') AND from_id != '".$uid."' AND (to_delete='1' OR from_delete='1') AND is_chat='1' GROUP BY from_id,to_id ORDER by created DESC;");
```

But if you want make something more cakeway:

[CakeBook: find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find)

In more complex query sometimes you can't make it easy. Sometimes you only have to use raw query, or rethink your query.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `query()` for this one. That function should be used when you can't reproduce a query with cake methods. But this is a simple one that can be done with `find()`